# Am I able to limit the use of eval()? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, eval

I am making a program that takes in a bunch of input and returns something based on it. Like if the person does `3 + 4 - (77 ** 3)`, but how can I limit it so that the person using it is only able to do that. As in, can I limit it so the person can't type in `print("")`, because that will return `""`. Can I make it so that he can only do math operations? Or is that not possible and a too much of a question?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: You can limit it by not using eval and instead parsing the mathematical expression yourself.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is safer than `eval`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval.  `json` is also a good tool for creating valid dictionaries and lists.  `sympy`  handles symbolic math.  Beyond that I can imagine using `re` to test for valid characters such as the digits and `+-/*`.

Comment: @hpaulj really, this is a job for [`pyparsing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/1.5.7) not `re` if you want to do it right.

Comment: PLease clarify what you exactly want to have. Here we can help you resolve or improve problem and this not a coding website, please take note of it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga or maybe even the `numexpr` library... but that won't stop things like `987549873245987329754  ** 87345987324958732579324875932874593287459328745973259873249587324957324957932487593248759832457932875932847593287459328745932847593287459324875932847593475` going on...

Comment: Thanks for anyone who responded here, but I found a much better way without using eval() or exec(). :)

Comment: @pvg Thanks for the response, I have actually tried something similar to what you stated! :)

Answer (score -1):

I use built in functions, like `.isalpha()` , and tuples to limit the use of `eval()` . I personally built a simple calculator, and limited out all words and letters via a tuple, checked by a loop over the input string.
  This prevents code from being passed through, where only a mathematical function should be.

Good luck: )